# Pre-commit hook fails due to "E205000: Invalid revision number supplied"

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Im trying to setup a pre-commit hook for email notification using VisualSVN.  When I try to add a test file to the repository and commit it, I get an error that includes verbage such as "VisualSVNServerHooks: E205000: Invalid revision number supplied..."

Im using the basic email notification setup referenced from here
https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/

What Im using (settings changed)

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
    commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
    --from "noreply@nowhere.com" --to "my_email_address@somewhere.com " ^
    --smtp-server mail.something.com
```

If I dummy up the command and replate %2 with 123, it works. Could the 2nd argument not be getting supplied to the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be a **post-commit** hook, not pre-commit. Pre-commit hook runs before new revision is created in a repository, therefore it does not supply a revision number as %2 input parameter.

Comment: Duh!  It even says <b>post-commit</b> in the documentation link I posted.  for some reason my brain read it as pre-commit.  I updated the settings and it works as expected now.  Thank you!